# How to rename many groups of rows in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a list of lists:

result_list = [[10x20], [10x10], [10x5], [10x2], [10x20, [10x10], [10x5] ....[10x2]]

Inside each [ ] there are 10 values. I imported this list of lists to a Pandas Dataframe,I calculated the average and rounded to 2 decimals.

I need to rename the rows. As an image is better to explain, I added 2 pictures.

Dataframe I have: 
[image]

Dataframe I need: 
[image]

Now the code:

```
   df.loc['AWA'] = [[0:4], :]
   df.loc['REM'] = [[4:8], :]
   df.loc['S1'] = [[8:12], :]
   df.loc['S2'] = [[12:16], :]
   df.loc['SWS'] = [[16:20], :]
   df.loc['stades'] = [[20:24], :]
```

I also thought of "group by". But how can I use it when my rows do not have a name?

Comment: Not sure to understand each x20, x10, x5, x2 packets combine with your raw rows in your dataframe. Are you suggesting in your raw dataframe (first picture) that rows 0 to 19 should be indexed ('AWA', '10x20'), then the lines 20 to 29 ('AWA', '10x10') etc. or you want something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume I have this `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(24, 10))
df['Total Acc'] = df.sum(1)
df
```

[image]

Create a new index and assign it

```
lvl0 = ['AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'stades']
lvl1 = ['10x20', '10x10', '10x5', '10x2', ]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([lvl0, lvl1])
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I wanted. I have never heard of 'MultiIndex' before. :)