# How to do a stacked bar plot in Pandas using the rows' names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, visualization

I want a create a stacked bar plot from my dataframe. I used MultiIndex to rename the rows [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076070/how-to-rename-many-groups-of-rows-in-pandas/40076284#40076284). I want to plot only the last column (Total Acc). This is what I have so far:

MY DATAFRAME:
[image]

PLOT I GET:

[image]

PLOT I WANT:

[image]
This is the code I have written:

```
    e=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100   #Here I isolate the last column
    e.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

EDIT:

I have improved the code.

```
   e=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100
   row_awa = e.loc['AWA'] 
   row_rem = e.loc['REM'] 
   row_s1 = e.loc['S1'] 
   row_s2 = e.loc['S2'] 
   row_sws = e.loc['SWS'] 
   row_stades = e.loc['stades'] 

   row_awa.plot.bar(stacked=True) 
   row_rem.plot.bar(stacked=True) 
   row_s1.plot.bar(stacked=True) 
   row_s2.plot.bar(stacked=True) 
   row_sws.plot.bar(stacked=True) 
   row_stades.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

But it still does not work!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate someone who is making an actual draw of a chart with colour and everything. Using the previous dataframe you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(24, 10))
df['Total Acc'] = df.sum(1)
lvl0 = ['AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'stades']
lvl1 = ['10x20', '10x10', '10x5', '10x2', ]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([lvl0, lvl1])
```

now you want a 'stacked' bar chart. undo your work by reseting that index, pivot the table and plot the chart:

```
df.reset_index().pivot('level_0', 'level_1', 'Total Acc').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]